# Differentiating Shannon's entropy

Tags: self-study, entropy, proof

Can somebody please show the steps of how differentiation of Shannon's entropy yields the following result?

$H = -\sum_{l=0}^{L-1} p(l)\log_2[p(l)]$

The result of differentiating is
$H_m = -\sum_{l=0}^{L-1} \frac{1}{L}\log_2[\frac{1}{L}]$ = $log_2 L $

Comment: differentiating to find its maximum? that is when all probabilities are $\frac{1}{L}$

Comment: Differentiating with respect to what?  Ordinarily there are no variables in the entropy formula: it is a function of a discrete frequency distribution.

Comment: Response to “ ... no variables in the entropy formula ...”: Variables are the index numbers i=1 to n and the associated probabilities. Ref. Shannon’s Theorem2  in the original paper "Mathematical Theory of Communication", Bell System Technical Journal vol 27 July October 1948. The discrete case is generalized to continuous entropy, defined as an integral over support X and P(x) is a PDF.  Shannon points out “If x is limited to a certain volume V then H(x) is maximum equal to logV when P(x) is constant 1/V in the volume”. This is equivalent to the above where L replaces Shannon's V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please excuse me if I just modify your notation slightly so that I can type it quickly:

1) Replace l (small letter "el") with x so as to avoid any confusion with 1=number one. 
2) p = p(x) is implied. 
3)Type the summation sign as "Sigma", with the summation from x=0 to x=L-1 implied, and 4) log=log2 or, without loss of generality, any other base simply with units conversion.

Explanation:

Step 1) Definition of Shannon entropy: $H = H(x) = -\Sigma[p*log(p)]$
This corresponds to what you have written correctly as the first equation.

Step 2) Differentiating is done so as to locate the maximum entropy, $H_m$, which occurs when the derivative is zero.

Step 3) Maximum entropy occurs when all states are equi-probable, i.e. $p = p(x) = \frac1{L}$ for all values of x in the range 0 to L-1.

Step 4) Substituting this into the original Shannon entropy equation:
$H_m = H.maximum = -\Sigma[(\frac1{L})*log(\frac1{L})]$ 
Because $log(\frac1{L})$ is a constant, this can be taken outside the summation, and so
$H_m = -log(\frac1{L})*\Sigma[\frac1{L}]$ and, as the summation is over the range 0 to L-1, i.e. consists L elements each of width $x = \frac1{L}$, therefore $\Sigma[\frac1{L}] = 1$.

Step 5) Substituting from 4): $H_m = -1*log(\frac1{L}) = log(L)$
Q.E.D, as required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That means there is no differentiation?We are just putting the value of 1/L to denote maximum entropy?Is my understanding correct? Secondly, I have another question if you may kindly address it. Entropy = negative of information.So what can we say about information at maximum entropy?Will information decrease when entropy is maximum due to the negative correspondence?

Comment: The confusion here seems to be the following. The extremum of any function f(x) occurs at the value of x, say xo, where the derivative df/dx=0. Evaluating f(xo) gives the maximum of f. Here f(x)=H(x) for the case where x takes only discrete values. Your question does not actually dislpay the derivative dH/dx but simply shows the evaluation H(x)=Hmaximum at the point where the derivative is zero. If p(x) is some arbitrary PDF then the maximum of H occurs if p(x) is everywhere equal. In the discrete case x takes only integer values i over the range 0 to L-1. As sum(p(x))=1, therefore Hmax=1/L

Comment: To obtain a qualitative understanding, saying "Entropy = negative of information" is not correct. In the context of Information as expressed by Claude Shannon, Entropy is a measure of the uncertainty in a random variable or a measure of the UNPREDICTABILITY of (new) information content. For example, if someone makes a statement confirming what you already know, that statement is less useful than if they tell you something you don't know. New information that concerns something uncertain that you don't know will be more helpful to you, and the entropy associated with such information is high.